# Existence of minimum norm solution to linear equation $Tx =y$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $T: X \to Y$ be a bounded linear map between Hilbert spaces $(X, \langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle_X)$ and $(Y, \langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle_Y)$ (the Hilbert spaces may be complex or just real spaces). Suppose that $y$ is in the range $\mathcal{R}(T)$ of our operator, so that $T^{-1}(y)$ is a nonempty, closed subset of $X$.

Let $ \alpha = \inf \{\|x\|_X : x\in T^{-1}(y) \} \ge 0.$

> I would like to show that there exists a unique $x_0 \in T^{-1}(y) $ such that $\|x_0\| = \alpha$.

My attempt so far:

We may choose a sequence $\{x_n\} \subseteq T^{-1}(y)$ so that $\|x_n \| \to \alpha $. This sequence is bounded in norm, hence it has subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ that is weakly convergent to some $x' \in X$. My hope is that I can show $x'$ is the desired element $x_0$ that I seek. But I have gotten stuck.

One other observation I have made is that, while $T^{-1}(y)$ is not necessarily a subspace of $X$, it is a convex subset of $X$. That is, for $x_1, x_2 \in T^{-1}(y)$ and $\lambda \in (0,1)$, we have $T(\lambda x_1 + (1 -\lambda) x_2) = \lambda T( x_1) + (1 -\lambda) T( x_2) = y.$

Hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: "it is a convex subset", a _closed_ convex subset. Now, Hilbert space, closed convex subset, minimum norm, wasn't there something about that?

Comment: @DanielFischer --- I am familiar with the following fact: If $C$ is a closed subspace of a Hilbert space $X$ and $x \notin C$, then there exists an element $d \in C$ minimizing $\{\|c - x\| : c \in C\}.$ Do you mean that this result also holds if we just take $C$ closed and convex, rather than making the stronger assumption that $C$ be a closed subspace?

Comment: Yes. Although the case of a closed subspace is arguably the _most_ important case, the more general case of closed convex (nonempty) subsets is also important. Take a look at the proof, and see whether you used anywhere that $C$ is a linear subspace, or whether only the convexity is used. [If the proof doesn't go through unchanged for $C$ nonempty closed and convex, it will require only small modifications.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see it directly using the orthogonal decomposition
$$
                 X = \mathcal{N}(T)\oplus\mathcal{N}(T)^{\perp}.
$$
If $Tx=y$, then $x=x'+x''$ for unique $x'\in\mathcal{N}(T)$, $x''\in\mathcal{N}(T)^{\perp}$. And $Tx=Tx''$. If $Tw=y$ also holds then $w''=x''$ because $w''-x''\in\mathcal{N}(T)^{\perp}\bigcap\mathcal{N}(T)$. So, with a small abuse of notation,
$$
                      T^{-1}(y) = x''\oplus\mathcal{N}(T),
$$
from which it follows that $x''$ is the unique element of $T^{-1}(y)$ of smallest norm.